# Hibernate cascade persistence: child object is saved but ID not assigned (in only one case)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm starting an small Spring Boot project with Hibernate, and I created a parent entity `GameDefinition`, who will manage its children's persistance:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class GameDefinition {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gameDefinition", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<GamePointDefinition> pointDefinitions = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters

    public void addGamePointDefinition(GamePointDefinition entity) {
        this.pointDefinitions.add(entity);
        entity.setGameDefinition(this);
    }
}
```

And its child entity `GamePointDefinition`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_pointdef")
public class GamePointDefinition {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "game_pointdef_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", nullable = false)
    private GameDefinition gameDefinition;

    // other fields

    // getters and setters

    public void setGameDefinition(GameDefinition gameDefinition) {
        this.gameDefinition = gameDefinition;
    }
}
```

I created a repository component using the Spring Data `Repository` object:

```
public interface GameDefinitionRepository extends Repository<GameDefinition, Long> {
    Optional<GameDefinition> findById(Long id);
    GameDefinition save(GameDefinition entity);
}
```

I setup some unit tests with `SpringRunner` and using H2 as database (Hibernate generates the schema)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class, TestConfiguration.class })
public class GameDefinitionRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private GameDefinitionRepository repository;

    @Autowired // util bean defined in TestConfiguration
    private IntegrationUtil integrationUtil;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        integrationUtil.truncateDatabase();
    }

    // other passing tests

    @Test
    public void testCascadeAddGamePointDefinitions() {
        GameDefinition saved = new GameDefinition();
        saved.setName(...);  // set other fields

        GamePointDefinition point1 = new GamePointDefinition();
        point1.setName(...);  // set other fields
        GamePointDefinition point2 = new GamePointDefinition();
        point2.setName(...);  // set other fields
        saved.addGamePointDefinition(point1);
        saved.addGamePointDefinition(point2);

        saved = repository.save(saved);

        GameDefinition fetched = repository.findById(saved.getId()).get();
        assertEquals(2, fetched.getPointDefinitions().size());
        assertThat(fetched.getPointDefinitions(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(point1.getId()))));
        assertThat(fetched.getPointDefinitions(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(point2.getId()))));

        GamePointDefinition point3 = new GamePointDefinition();  // (**)
        point3.setName(...);  // set other fields
        saved.addGamePointDefinition(point3);

        saved = repository.save(saved);

        fetched = repository.findById(saved.getId()).get();
        assertEquals(3, fetched.getPointDefinitions().size());
        assertThat(fetched.getPointDefinitions(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(point1.getId()))));
        assertThat(fetched.getPointDefinitions(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(point2.getId()))));
        assertThat(fetched.getPointDefinitions(), hasItem(hasProperty("id", is(point3.getId()))));  // (*)
    }
}
```

When I run the test class, my `testCascadeAddGamePointDefinitions` fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("id", is null)
     but: property 'id' was <5L>, property 'id' was <6L>, property 'id' was <7L>
    at ....
```

The error is thrown in the line marked by `// (*)`. That means, the `point3` object was saved, and it has an id in DB, but the `id` in the object *is still null*. What makes it weird is that `point1` and `point2` objects *does get its `id` set by the DB*. (confirmed in the debugger).

Also, using the fetched version of the parent instead of the persisted first object (ie. `saved = fetched;` in the line just before the one with `// (**)`) does return the same error in the same place.

Debugging, I find that `point1` and `point2` were inserted the original `ArrayList`, and after `save`, the `ArrayList` becomes a `PersistentBag` that holds the original `point1` and `point2` instances. But in the second save, the contents of the `PersistentBag` becomes 3 new objects, different (in memory) than the ones I instantiate in the test.

Why does it act different in each case? And it's possible to save and assign the ID to the `point3` object?

PD: the testing `application.properties`:

```
# Database configuration
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

# Hibernate configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: You need to set GameDefinition object in point definition objects. GamePointDefinition point1 = new GamePointDefinition(); point1.setName(...); point1.setGameDefinition(saved); Same for all the game definition points has to be done.

Comment: @AbhayJain That's what the `saved.addGamePointDefinition()` method does: it does the list adding and the parent setting in one place. I was reading this is a good practice when dealing with cascading entities.

Comment: Got it, I missed that code earlier. Can you reverse the order of code I.e set the game definition first, then add it to list? This is because list will have point definition which does not have reference to game definition which will prevent it to save with game definition id.